# Make a plane appear only on capture

Tags: javascript, instagram, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

Just started working in Spark AR and it seems pretty easy to make an object not visible when capturing, whether that is using the CameraInfo class or ObjectVisibility class. I've gotten that to work. However, what I can't get to work is the opposite. Basically, I have a plane with a texture attached that I would like to be hidden while the filter runs, but then when capturing a photo the plane becomes visible.

I thought I could just reverse the logic of how it worked above, basically with something like "if camera is capturing photo, then plane.hidden = false.) Or something like that, written in non-pseudocode of course. But that doesn't work. My guess is that there isn't enough time elapsing between the capture instruction to allow the plane visibility to be enabled, but could be wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you share your actual code please?